# CSS & AJAX - Complex Loading Spinners?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

With all the advancements with jQuery Mobile and cool CSS tricks, I was hoping there would be a couple better looking and more complex spinners out there. I'm thinking of the type of spinners you see in a well-designed videogame. I'm partial to the ones that have one circle going clockwise, another going counter-clockwise, maybe with a variation of size on top of that... Does anyone have any idea how they'd try to accomplish this using CSS/JS/GIF? Maybe doubling up 2 normal spinners on top of each other?

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.3 (latest) and I have absolutely no intention of worrying about IE... :)

Comment: Yeah, make one that looks the way you like? SO can't really tell you how to implement something you vaguely described in prose.

Comment: You can find a curated collection of spinners here: https://github.com/yangshun/awesome-spinners

Answer (score 3):

You can customize a `.gif` loader icon with http://ajaxload.info/

Comment: Voted up for being the first. Lets note there's a lot of people out there, just google "ajax gif" https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+gif